# Mocking functions called from within another in golang

Tags: go, glide-golang

I am trying to stub `os.Stat` and `ioutil.ReadFile(path)` as used the code below or if you like here on go playground [1]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func AssignFileValueFrom(path string, val *string) {
    var (
        tempValue []byte
        err       error
    )

    if _, err = os.Stat(path); err == nil {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("There was a os stat error:", err)
        }

        tempValue, err = ioutil.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("There was an io read error:", err)
        }
        *val = strings.TrimSpace(string(tempValue))
    }
}
```

I have used testify and tried following the example here [2]

```
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type osMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (o osMock) Stat(path string) (interface{}, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func TestAssignFileValueFrom(t *testing.T) {
    var test string
    osm := new(osMock)
    osm.On(`Stat`, `./.test`).Return([]byte(`1`), nil)

    AssignFileValueFrom(`./.test`, &test)
    // assert.Equal(t, `1`, test)
    osm.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

What am I not doing correctly??

[1] https://play.golang.org/p/xcbdMkMwoBN

[2] https://github.com/stretchr/testify#mock-package

Comment: You didn't mock anything. I suggest you pass a io.Reader to AssignFileValueFrom instead of a path. You don't need to write tests for the std lib, it already has tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with `osMock` doesn't any how influence execution of `AssignFileValueFrom` function. There is a direct call of `os.Stat` and it won't be substituted just because you have declared `osMock` somewhere.
To do actual testing you should use `interface`s and dependency injection to be able to test your code.
First of all `os.Stat` call must be substituted with call to your struct that implements an interface with same method defined. And you need to create at least 2 implementations of this interface: 1 - is actual working code to use, 2 - mock as your `osMock` struct to use in test. And you need to inject it or pass it to `AssignFileValueFrom` and then use to call `Stat` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys for your inputs I have rewritten my tests as follows..

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

var (
    err      error
    testFile *os.File
    test string
)

const (
    TestPrefix  = `test_file_prefix`
    FileContent = `1234`
)

func init() {
    testFile, err = ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), TestPrefix)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = ioutil.WriteFile(testFile.Name(), []byte(FileContent), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func TestAssignFileValueFrom(t *testing.T) {
    AssignFileValueFrom(testFile.Name(), &test)

    assert.Equal(t, test, FileContent)
}
```